# How can I replace only a given key for a specific file in this ad-hoc file format with UNIX tools (sed/awk/etc)?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I want to replace the `location` values in file 1 with the values found in file 2. For example, with the sample given, `location` values should change from 24 to 32 and from 25 to 34.

---

#### File 1:

```
'location': '24'
'Size':'8'
'location':'25'
'Size':2'
```

#### File 2:

```
32
34
```

#### Output

```
'location': '32'
'Size':'8'
'location':'34'
'Size':'2'
```

Comment: Don't force someone to click through and read the body before they even know what the question is. (Edited to try to address that issue).

Comment: "File 2" doesn't _have_ a location at all. Or do you mean the one under `Output`?

Comment: Beyond that: If folks are going to write tools for editing a file format, they need a _specification_ of that format, not just an example, to make sure that the code is correct. (This is part of why most folks use JSON, YAML, or otherwise something well-specified rather than hand-rolling their own formats; having a firm spec means that it's possible to have confidence in an implementation's correctness and completeness, and to know which side is wrong when two components aren't compatible with each other).

Comment: Please edit the question to show more clearly the `File 1` information, the `File 2` information, and the desired output.  It appears that maybe the first 'location' entry in `File 1` should have the value replaced by the first value in `File 2`, and the second location entry in `File 1` should have the value replaced by the second value in `File 2`.  Am I right in guessing that spaces are not all that significant, but should be preserved?  What should happen if there are more location entries in File 1 than there are lines in File 2?

Comment: Yes you are right..just need to update the location value with new values from different file

Comment: Thanks for updating, Paul.  I've flagged the question for reopening; it is now answerable (IMO).  It would be good if you could say what should happen if there are more locations in File 1 than there are entries in File 2.  Two primary alternatives are "leave the File 1 entries unchanged after the map runs out" and "use the last File 2 entry for all subsequent locations in File 1".  There may be others (cycle through the list from File 2 again is one such).

Comment: There will be same number of values in file2 as the number of location in file1.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you showed what you've tried, explaining where you're having problems.  You should probably use `awk`, and you should probably process `File 2` before processing `File 1`, using `FNR == NR` to process the lines from `File 2` and `FNR != NR` to process lines from `File 1`. You'd run `awk '…script that you write…' File2 File1` to process the files in the order `File 2` then `File 1`.  Choose filenames without blanks; they make life easier.

Comment: There are supposed to be as many location entries in File 2 as there are in File 1 — but things seldom work correctly all the time.  However, we can ignore that issue pro tempore.  Since you're learning the basics, we can ignore the complications of 'real life'.

Comment: I was trying to do it with sed command but its not working..I am just a beginner

Comment: I'd hate to do it with `sed`.  It probably can be done, but it would be anything but easy.

Comment: Oh okay i understand,using awk is much better here

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True with POSIX sed, but not that hard with GNU sed

Comment: Technically, your ad-hoc format appears to be valid [TOML](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0).

Comment: @chepner — Are you sure?  The stuff I see uses `=` in place of `:` in the question.  Where a colon is used, it is part of a JSON equivalent or simply punctuation in comments or text.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think so; `location: '24'` is definitely legal; I'm not *entirely* sure that you are allowed to quote the key with `:`, but `'location' = '24'` would be legal, so I'm assuming you can.

Comment: OK.  I must have missed where the spec said colon instead of equals is okay, but I thought I'd looked fairly hard.

Comment: I only knew because that's what was used in the sample file for something my company uses.

Answer (score 1):

#### First a solution with `awk`

```
awk -F"'" -v OFS="'" '
        $2 == "location" { getline $4 < "file2" }
        1
' file1
```

Explanation: each line is split with delimiter `'` and on evey "location" line, we replace the value (field `$4`) with a value read (`getline`) from file2. If file2 has not enough values, then the line is unchanged.

#### Now the same with `sed`

```
sed "s/.*/'location':'&'/" file2 \
| sed -e "
        /^'location'/ ! b
        R /dev/stdin
        d
" file1
```

Explanation: GNU `sed` has an [`R` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) that works similarly to the `getline` command in `awk`. We first transform file2 so as its line look like file1 (first `sed`) and then we pipe the result into the other `sed` command. Each time the latter sees a "location" line, it replaces it with one that it reads from `stdin`. This time, if file2 has not enough values, then the line is deleted.